# max function with more than one result for every group

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm looking for help with postgresql query.

Example input data are as follows:

```
pk  name
=========================
1   | notebook cz-2001
2   | notebook cz-2002
3   | notebook cz-2003
4   | notebook cz-2003
5   | notebook cz-2003
6   | notebook cz-2004
7   | notebook cz-2004
8   | notebook cz-2004
9   | notebook cz-2004
10  | notebook cz-2005
11  | notebook cz-2006
12  | notebook cz-2007
13  | notebook cz-2008
14  | notebook cz-2009
```

Some rows have same value in name column (notebook cz-2003, notebook cz-2004)

I can get one maximum pk value for grouped names by this query:

```
select * from test_group where pk in
(
select max(pk) from test_group group by name order by name
)
```

Result:

```
pk  name
=========================
1   | notebook cz-2001
2   | notebook cz-2002
5   | notebook cz-2003
9   | notebook cz-2004
10  | notebook cz-2005
11  | notebook cz-2006
12  | notebook cz-2007
13  | notebook cz-2008
14  | notebook cz-2009
```

but I have no idea and that is my question how to get for example two (three, four...) highest pk values for grouped names.

Expected result for example for two highest pk:

```
pk  name
=========================
1   | notebook cz-2001
2   | notebook cz-2002
4   | notebook cz-2003
5   | notebook cz-2003
8   | notebook cz-2004
9   | notebook cz-2004
10  | notebook cz-2005
11  | notebook cz-2006
12  | notebook cz-2007
13  | notebook cz-2008
14  | notebook cz-2009
```

Could you give me some hints how to achieve that?

Thanks

JP

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [`row_number()` window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html) for that:

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=1149e169cba1b440891d018e6979d90c)

```sql
SELECT pk, name
FROM
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY pk DESC)
    FROM my_table
) s
WHERE row_number <= 2    -- or any other value
```

`row_number()` window function add a row number to a certain ordered group. Here your group is the `name` column and the order is by `pk` (descending because you want the highest numbers counted first).

With the `WHERE` clause you can filter the first n records (which were numbered with 1, 2, ...) or any other elements you like.

Answer (score 0):

One method is window functions:

```
select tg.*
from (select tg.*,
             row_number() over (partition by name order by pk desc) as seqnum
      from test_group tg
     ) tg
where seqnum <= ?;
```

Another method -- more in line with your current approach -- is a correlated subquery:

```
select tg.*
from test_group tg
where tg.pk >= any (select tg2.pk
                    from test_group tg2
                    where tg2.name = tg.name
                   );
```